# Libgdx touchdragged returning strange x,y coordinates

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to make a fish character move wherever the player puts their finger. I'm doing this using libgdx's touch dragged. For some reason, the x and y coordinates where the touch is registered is only giving me one number, and doesn't seem to be on screen. I've read other questions related to libgdx touchdragged here, but can't find anyone else having an issue like this. For now, I'm just trying to make the fish move in the basic directions (N, NW, W, etc.) Eventually I will use the delta to make it move to the touch location.

This is the coordinates it keeps giving me in the console:

```
08-17 15:12:16.181  11497-11595/? I/2367﹕ 721
08-17 15:12:16.211  11497-11595/? I/2362﹕ 728
08-17 15:12:16.231  11497-11595/? I/2359﹕ 733
08-17 15:12:16.251  11497-11595/? I/2356﹕ 736
```

I'm using Gdx.app.log to log the values, but I can't make any sense of it. This is the code for the onClick:

```
public void onClick(int clickX, int clickY) {
    Gdx.app.log(String.valueOf(clickX),String.valueOf(clickY));
    if (this.getX() - clickX < 0){
        velocity.x = -5;
    }
    if (this.getX() - clickX > 0){
        velocity.x = 5;
    }
    if (this.getY() - clickY < 0){
        velocity.y = 5;
    }
    if (this.getY() - clickY > 0) {
        velocity.y = -5;
    }
}
```

And lastly, the inputHandler class (relevant area):

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    myFish.onClick(screenX,screenY);
    return true;
}
```

Currently my fish keeps moving towards the bottom left, no matter what I do and I think it's due to the strange x,y coordinates.

I've also tried using `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()`, but keep getting the same issue (large single coordinates).

I'm not sure if `screenX` and `screenY` are the correct values to use, but using both `screenX` and `Gdx.input.getX()` still give me the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer entirely your question but you need to unproject your click/drag coordinate to translate them to your gameworld coordinate system. This is done like this:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    Vector3 v = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
    v = camera.unproject(v);
    myFish.onClick(v.x, v.y);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My follow up question is what's the best way to pass screenX and screenY to get unprojected. Currently, my camera is in a class I have to do the game rendering and touchDragged() is in an inputHandler class. I'm guessing making a new camera just for the sake of grabbing the coordinates is not the most efficient way to go about doing this, but I can't see an easy way to pass the screenX and screenY values up to my GameRenderer.class since they're essentially in different branches.

Comment: A good way is pass the object that have the camera. Suppose that is called `MyGdxGame game`, pass this class to the constructor of your input handler, something like `public class MyInputHandler(MyGdxGame game)`, then in the `touchDragged()` of this class call `game.getCamera()`. Another way is to make the camera static (but I don't recommend this), there are several ways.